# R Shiny - clicking shinyTree expanding icon close parent dropdown modal

Tags: r, shiny, shinytree

I am using library shinyTree and shinyWidgets. The problem is that if I put the hierarchical checkbox on the dropdown modal, the double clicking of the tree expanding icon (see the red circle in the following figure) will close the parent dropdown modal.

[image]

Any solution regarding this?

Full source code:

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$shinyTreeTest <- renderUI({ 
    dropdown(
      shinyTree("tree", checkbox = TRUE),
      style = "unite", label = "Location", width = "300px", circle=FALSE
    )
  })

  output$tree <- renderTree({ 
    list(  'I lorem impsum'= list( 
      'I.1 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.1.1 lorem impsum'='1', 'I.1.2 lorem impsum'='2'),stselected=TRUE),  
      'I.2 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.2.1 lorem impsum'='3'), stselected=TRUE)))

  })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

shinyUI(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    h4('Shiny hierarchical checkbox')
    ,uiOutput("shinyTreeTest")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question on GitHub shinyWidget project and got the answer from there. The problem has been solved by reinstalling shinyWidget from devtool rather than CRAN.